# Shortest way to list multiple conditions in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a shorter way to use  `OR` in PHP for the following?

```
if($cat->getId()==44 || $cat->getId()==8 || $cat->getId()==24)
```

Like for example, a syntactically correct way like:-

```
if($cat->getId()==44, 8, 24
```

Without using `in_array()` because in this instance, it isn't simple to predefine the category ID's.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit 04/02/2015

Wasn't aware of the shortened `in_array()` syntax introduced in PHP 5.4 so upgraded PHP on the server and this works perfectly for what I'm after - thanks for answers pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try being a bit creative. You could use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) for example. 
Rule of thumb: ***If you think there is a simpler way to write an expression, there is one.***

```
<?php

$ids = [44,8,24];

if( in_array($cat->getId(), $ids) )
{
    echo "Do Something";
}
```

or in one line:

```
<?php

if( in_array($cat->getId(), [44,8,24]) )
{
    echo "Do Something";
}
```

Comment: I was reluctant to use `in_array()` like your suggestion in this instance because hundreds of `if` statements will be in use in the file to display specific data... I'd have to use lots of different variables for different category ID's based on various conditions required.

Comment: Then you have flaws in your design. It's not a question of simplifying expressions.

Comment: Sorry, your latter answer will work - I just saw that edit - thank you :)

Comment: Marked as the correct answer for the latter shortened syntax which I was not aware of as I wasn't even running PHP 5.4. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) -

```
$array = array(44, 8, 24);
if(in_array($cat->getId(), $array)) {
```

Comment: I was reluctant to use `in_array()` like your suggestion in this instance because hundreds of `if` statements will be in use in the file to display specific data... I'd have to use lots of different variables for different category ID's based on various conditions required.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion best way is:

```
if(in_array($cat->getId(), array(44, 8, 24))
{
...
}
```

In newer (5.5+) versions of PHP you can use short array notation e.g.:

```
if(in_array($cat->getId(), [44, 8, 24])
{
...
}
```

Comment: As of PHP **5.4** you can use the short array syntax.

Comment: Thanks very much - had to update PHP 5.3 to 5.4 and now am able to use this shorterned syntax which I was unaware of - thanks very much :)